# How to change the position of headers in the table wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Now I have a post_type created, called products

[image]

This shows me a table in the following order:

- Title
- Category
- Date
- Price
- Mileage

As I can change the position as follows:

- Title
- Category
- Price
- Mileage
- Date

???

I thank you help me, thanks

Comment: What is your question?  Can you provide us with your code, in an MCVE?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_productos_posts_columns', 'column_order_move_1');
function column_order_move_1($columns) {
  $n_columns = array();
  $move = 'Price'; // what to move
  $before = 'Date'; // move before this
  foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
    if ($key==$before){
      $n_columns[$move] = $move;
    }
      $n_columns[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $n_columns;
}

add_filter('manage_productos_posts_columns', 'column_order_move_2');
function column_order_move_2($columns) {
  $n_columns = array();
  $move = 'Mileage'; // what to move
  $before = 'Date'; // move before this
  foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
    if ($key==$before){
      $n_columns[$move] = $move;
    }
      $n_columns[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $n_columns;
}
```

It's not the best solution.